# Missing .h file, in-spite of linking .so files from library folder

Tags: c++, linux, embedded

I am new to Linux, I am currently trying to use API programming features from a ***ginkgo USB-CAN interface***. To program the API using C++ they provide library files which contains three files with **.so** files . I have to link them to the C++ program.

It needs a ***Ginkgo_driver.h*** they only provide with three files in the library **libGinkgo_Driver.so**,  **libusb.so** , **libusb-1.0.so**. I tried all the linking methods described online like using the  L./lib/libGinkgo_Driver.so etc.. I still get the same error

> " fatal error: Ginkgo_Driver.h: No such file or directory  #include
>   "Ginkgo_Driver.h"

I use Linux 64 bit system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Using `#include "foo.h"` will search only in the current folder. Either give a full path, or *install* that package so it can be found by the compiler whe used as `#include <foo>`

Comment: If your code is #including `Ginkgo_Driver.h` then you need that header file - it's not part of the .so files.

Comment: @Ripi2 Normally `"..."` searches system directories as well, after the current folder.

Comment: You should be able to tell the compiler the folders or directories that you want searched for header files.

Comment: If these functions can be found by the linker, you can declare them as `extern` without including the header file

Comment: No amount of "linking" anything will resolve your problem;  there are three stages to a build - preprocessing, compilation, linking - file inclusion is a pre-processor action, not a linker action.  The .so files are irrelevant.

Comment: The example at https://github.com/ViewTool2015/Ginkgo/tree/master/Linux%20GCC/Ginkgo%20CAN/LinuxGCC_USB_CAN_Test includes ControlCAN.h - possibly that has the declarations you need.  Comment-out the include to see what undeclared symbols result, then see if they are in ControlCAN.h and include that instead if that is the case.  It'll be easier to find the symbol declarations you need that the file that does not exist.

Comment: @Clifford Yes you're right. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no header file called Ginkgo_driver.h , instead I had to include ControlCAN.h that is in they have in their example program. Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Note that this is a *compile* error, not a *link* error.  Compile and link dependencies are distinct -L does nothing for compilation, though of course they have to correspond.